# Export Archived Emails from Enterprise Vault

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, email-client, exchange-2013

I am working in an company that uses Microsoft Exchange as email server and Symantec Enterprise Vault for Email Archiving.

I want to export all my emails to a .PST file. However, only non archived emails are exported. Note that I can open an archived email if I double click on it in Outlook 2016 given that I have the Enterprise Vault plugin installed.

My question is: Is there any third party tool or Email client that can recover my archived email and export them into .PST file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is a product you can use to export your items retrieving originals from EV. [Export Outlook Items to MSG Files](https://www.reliefjet.com/Essentials/Features/OutlookItemsExportMSG) utility does that. After that you can convert MSGs to PST using another utility the product provides (Import MSG Files to Outlook).

Here is the tutorial video on exporting Symantec Enterprise Vault items from Outlook: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_-78N1MOmo